# Rewrite Engine issue on Wamp

Tags: url, url-rewriting, wamp

i'm had hard moments trying to figure out how to implement a simple Rewrite engine rule in WAMP.

The target is to obtain ad uri like

```
www.mydomain.com/index/
```

from a request like

```
www.mydomain.com/index.php
```

Wamp keep telling me that there was an error in configuration file, when i try on my own.

Can you suggest a correct rule to accomplish this task?

thanks always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested it but it seems to be correct.

```
RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/$ /$1.php\
```

Make sure mod_rewite is enabled before using it.

Comment: When i try with your script with a request like  http://localhost/register.php the server write on the adress bar http://localhost/register.php that is the same url, while it should be localhost/register/. am i missing something? Rewrite Engine is enabled

Comment: OK it was the rewrite condition that didn't work, i removed it and now it works like a charm. Thanks